# Returning a lookup value from a dataframe to a variable

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
#Create DF
d = { 
     'Day': ['Mon','Tue','Wed','Thu','Fri','Sat','Sun'],
    'Staff Count':[20,18,17,16,15,7,6,],
    }
           
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df
```

[image]

I would simply like to return the staff count on Mondays to a variable `20`.

I have tried:

```
MonStaff = df.lookup(df.index[df.Day=='Mon'],df['Staff Count'])
```

to no avail but I'm sure it's something simple!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `df.loc[df.Day == 'Mon', 'Staff Count']` ? To get  as a scalar value: `df.loc[df.Day == 'Mon', 'Staff Count'].iat[0]`

Comment: `MonStaff = df.loc[df.Day == 'Mon', 'Staff Count'][0]` worked great thanks! if you put the solution up i can accept it!

Answer (score 0):

Transform your dataframe into a Series indexed by day and use simple indexing:

```
s = df.set_index('Day')['Staff Count']

s['Mon']
# 20
```

Or, if you have multiple columns:

```
df2 = df.set_index('Day')

df2.loc['Mon', 'Staff Count']
# 20
```

This will be efficient on the long run if you need to fetch multiple values.